# Beautiful Soup List of Words

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to find certain words within a website. Right now my code can only check for one word but I want it to be able to check for multiple words, (say instead of just checking for 'dog', i want it to check for ["dog","cat","adult"]

```
#Import Packages
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def count_words(url, the_word):
   r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
   words = soup.find(text=lambda text: text and the_word in text)
   print(words)



def main():
   url = 'https://patch.com/illinois/alsip-crestwood/pet-adoption-alsip-crestwood-area-see-latest- 
   dogs-cats-more'
   word= 'dog'
   count = count_words(url, word)
   print(url, count, word)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Basically I do not know how to pass in a list of words instead of one singular string!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're making it a bit too complicated than what is actually necessary. Try something like this:

```
url = "https://patch.com/illinois/alsip-crestwood/pet-adoption-alsip-crestwood-area-see-latest-dogs-cats-more"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

pets = ["dog","cat"]
for pet in pets:
    print(pet, len(soup.find_all(text=lambda text: text and pet in text)))
```

Output:

```
dog 13
cat 76
```

Comment: I want it to print out the content of the line though? not just how many times it occurs

Comment: @cbyoda Your question indicated you're interested in counting the occurrences. If that's not the case, you should edit your question and show exactly the expected output (or at least a representative sample).